# Can i sync a Google Fusion table with a public dropbox document?

Tags: real-time, synchronization, dropbox, google-fusion-tables

There is a public dropbox document that is updated every day or so. I am using this data in a Google Fusion table to do different types of visualization and analysis.

Can i set up the fusion table to auto update itself to pull out the data from dropbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.  You'd need to write a script to do this.  PHP, Python and Java FT client libraries exist which would allow you to do this.